# Any examples of any language bifurcating the past into past before one's life and past during one's life?

Tags: semantics, linguistic-typology, tense

It can be either from a conlang or a natlang but I wasn't able to find any examples.

Comment: Sounds similar to [evidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality) (though, of course, things you don't witness can happen in your lifetime).

Comment: While there are many languages of the world that discriminate between different degrees of past I am not aware of any language binding this distinction to the lifetime of the speaker.

Comment: From the pragmatic point of view, one can hardly have a need to often speak about the time before the speaker's birth as an exact point of time in the sense that for both the speaker and the listener the day of the speaker's birth makes a significant borderline in their attitude to things. On the other hand, there's a number of languages with the _mythological_ past tense which implies that the events described using this tense had definitely happened before everyone around, everyone in the whole world was born, which although partly, but still does fit your request.

Comment: Are you thinking of languages in cultures that believe in reincarnation?

Comment: Sorry, but what does "bifurcating the past into the past" even mean? That is not really linguistically valid...

Comment: @Lambie:   I'm pretty sure that he's referring to having more than one past tense:   one for past events that took place during the speaker's lifetime, and another for past events that took place before the speaker was born.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann Yes, I can see that. I doubt any past tenses do that. Divide things into the past before one's life and during one's life.